# Route controller isn't being found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when I type in /#/addOrder as a URL it shall load a template file. Right not I get some error and the index page is loaded twice.

t.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>asdad</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app = "mainApp">
<a href="#/addOrder">add</a>
   <div ng-view></div>

</div>    
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

tem.html

```
<h1>tem is loaded!</h1>

script.js

var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.

when('/addOrder', {
    templateUrl: 'tem.html', controller: 'activeOrderController'
}).

when('/viewStudents', {
    templateUrl: 'order/addOrders.html', controller: 'addOrderController'
}).
when('/viewStudents', {
    templateUrl: 'order/endedOrders.html', controller: 'endedOrderController'
}).

otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/t.html'
});

}]);
```

> Error: ng:areq Bad Argument
>
> Argument 'activeOrderController' is not aNaNunction, got undefined
>   Description
>   AngularJS often asserts that certain values will be present and truthy using a helper function. If the assertion fails, this error is thrown. To fix this problem, make sure that the value the assertion expects is defined and truthy.

[image]

Comment: not causing the error but note your `otherwise` needs to be a valid angular url defined in a `when`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing empty space between ng-app and "=".
ng-app="mainApp"

Also, create two controllers you refer in route config.

Answer (score 0):

You had wrong redirect statement & you had two routes with same statement `/viewStudents` name.

```
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/viewStudents'
});
```

Also you have to define all the controllers which are mention there on each route

```
mainApp.controller('activeOrderController', function(){
  //console.log('I am activeOrderController')
})
mainApp.controller('addOrderController', function(){
  //console.log('I am addOrderController')
})
mainApp.controller('endedOrderController', function(){
  //console.log('I am endedOrderController')
})
```